# DateTime formatting error in the MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing MVC app.
I am trying to format the date in view. 
In one statement it working fine , but in another statement showing the error.

Below statement work fine.

```
 @Model.CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm tt")
```

This statement generates an error.

```
@Model.ModifiedDate.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm tt")
```

Error is

> no overload method takes 1 string

Got the soultion

> Thanks to mattytommo

In Model I have set the property "Nullable" so I have to change the statement to

```
@Model.ModifiedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm tt")
```

Its working now...

Comment: Could you write your model with its props?

Comment: Is your `ModifiedDate` nullable?

Comment: Instead of editing your question to say you've solved the problem, you should mark @mattytommo's answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing `ModifiedDate` is `nullable`. If that's the case, try this (although you may want to perform `null` checking, otherwise it'll throw an error for `null` values):

```
@Model.ModifiedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: I am assuminig ModifiedDate column is of DateTime Type. Intelliscense is not showing Value property. Can you please explain more about this ?

Comment: @ewvfwrwwvw OP said it is nullable, which means the type is `DateTime?` **not** `DateTime`. All nullable types inherit the `Value` property.

Comment: @user1650894 No problems, if this was the answer please mark it as correct :)

Comment: BTW. I was not the victim.